# Transform text value according his length

Tags: html, css

I know there is a way to keep this functionality simple only using a bit of css, but i don't remember at all, what style property is that allows to make something like:

```
<p>150523215</p><!-- Without transform... -->
```

with transform (only allowing 2 digits):

```
<p>99+</p>
```

so the thing i need is very simple: **i need to display 99+ if the number is higher than 2 digits**, and display the real number if the number is 2 digits or lower, if it's possible i want that solution with only css (not javascript), thanks! :3

Comment: Nope. Not in CSS alone. JS has many options for you though

Comment: I believe you can only add the "..." at the end using text-overflow property

Comment: I know, but it is possible only using css?, i viewed some time ago that there is a possiblity to achieve this only using one css :3

Comment: I want to keep the 99+, (like a badge of notifications), but text-overflow with custom character is not supported in ionic4 at building...

Comment: Based on this post, only firefox supports passing custom text to text-overflow. Nevertheless I can't think a way in css to test if the element has more than 2 chars, making impossible to do what you are asking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401846/custom-text-overflow-css

Comment: I can write you a solution using vanilla javascript, if you want.

Comment: Thanks dear Luis!, ok is a great idea!,  but... some thing: the p element is only a 'template', the real app is changing values according some data, so... needing to be actualized according data...

Comment: Maybe when you get the data, you can say, if (data.length > 2) then "99+" else data, or even in the template using conditional statement inside ionic html template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type something like this is the Ionic html template

```
 <p> {{ value.length > 2 ? '99+' : value }}</p>
```

Comment: Ohhhh that's better!, this is using only the HTML and typescript data. i know there a  css possibility to make the same, but i'm not remember it, if there is some one that knows that css property please answer here, will be also usefull!