# Setting the amount of dots in text-overflow: ellipsis;

Tags: html, css, frontend

is there any option to set the specific number of dots in `text-overflow: ellipsis`. I would like to set the number to 2 instead of 3. I have tried to set it by adding pseudo-element `:after`, but it adds dots even if the text fits to div.

Actual behaviour: 
[image]

Expected behaviour: 
[image]
[image]

my css clases:

```
 .truncate-name {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.truncate-name::after {
    content: "..";
}
```

Comment: Ellipsis is an actual **character** defined as three dots so no not really. Frankly though, why bother with something so trivial?

Comment: Only way is to use `:after` more info in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37594018/styling-dots-on-text-overflow-ellipsis/37594427)

Comment: @user3681304 Yes, it does and its exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely out of luck @Bartosz, unless you only want to target Firefox users ;) Please see this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10349526/3681304

EDIT: There are no selectors for "overflown". As such there are no selectors for computed styles in CSS in general.